# cannot read property of undefined | react error

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json

I am trying to render info on UI, as IsMobileOnLease is a child node in JSON, i have used this to check the status of IsMobileOnLease but i am getting error as "cannot read property of undefined react".

```
this.mob.MobileLobList[0].MobileRiskList[0].IsMobileOnLease!=="undefined" && this.mob.MobileLobList[0].MobileRiskList[0].IsMobileOnLease=="Y"
                    ?
                    <UISelect label="IsMobileOnLease"  codeTableName="MobileData" model={this.mob} property="IsMobileOnLease" defaultValue='3' enabled={disabled} />
                    : 
                    <UISelect label="IsMobileOnLease"  codeTableName="MobileData" model={this.mob} property="IsMobileOnLease" defaultValue='5' enabled={disabled} />
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.mob.MobileLobList[0]?.MobileRiskList[0]?.IsMobileOnLease && this.mob.MobileLobList?.MobileRiskList?.IsMobileOnLease=="Y"
```